# Bundle identifier is missing. x doesn't have a bundle identifier. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm trying to build a release version for IOS using Codename One but it keeps failing because of the product_bundle_identifier missing. I've deleted the .codenameone/iosCerts folder as per [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/qzo8aj/bundle_identifier_is_missing_for_ios_ios_builds/) but I still get the error.
The certificates look like they're generating okay but I have no way to find out.
I was able to build a version a week or so ago but I had to bump the version number after trying to upload my release in the App Store. It broke after that for some reason

Comment: Did you refactor your packages at some point in time since the project creation? If so you need to make sure all the names everywhere in the pom, `codenameone_settings.properties` etc.  match perfectly to the new name and regenerate provisioning.

Comment: I changed the `codename1.packageName` and the `codename1.ios.appid` but the appid keeps changing to the old name. Can't find it in any files though. Any other settings I need to change? I don't have a pom, just changed it in the codenameone_settings.properties

The certificates keep changing to reflect the change as well.

It used to include our App Store team ID which I got rid of, it keeps being added though.

Comment: Are you using Ant or Maven? The pom applies to maven (which is the recommended way). If you open codenameone_settings or run the certificate wizard some settings might be reset. 
I suggest creating a new project in https://start.codenameone.com/ then copying your source over and trying to build via Maven.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using Ant structure i never has been problem with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Shai's comments I went ahead and started from scratch using the Initializr. Once I imported my `codenameone_settings.properties` I started receiving the same error again. With some trial and error I figured out the `codename1.arg.ios.plistInject` I had somehow caused the issue. The app builds and works fine without that line being in there.

Comment: If you'll include the text of the plistInject I might be able to help.

Comment: I no longer work on this project so I can't access the code anymore I'm afraid